Event Parameters Blocked in Stock Facebook iOS SDK Install
I'm seeing an 'event parameters blocked' diagnostic message in events manager after installing the Facebook iOS SDK in my mobile app. The system thinks this event holds personal data — ("You can't share data that includes or is based on health, financial, consumer report or otherwise sensitive information").
The offending parameter is fb_content_title, in all the payment events such as fb_mobile_purchase. When I look at my app logs and filter by FBSDK, I see that all this parameter contains is the name of my in-app purchase product. No personal data.
What can I do about this? Facebook business support were most unhelpful, not understanding my description of the issue at all, and suggesting it was a technical issue and I should raise a support ticket 'on the developers side'. There's no such support channel.
This is a stock install of the SDK, right from Meta's docs. No custom events or custom code of any kind.
